# Error: The reference to external elements from the source named 'master.dacpac' could not be resolved

Tags: sql-server, docker, dacpac, sqlpackage

I am building a database dacpac using sqlpackage on a windows machine. The project contains a reference to `master.dacpac`

I take the move the dacpac to a linux machine (`mssql-server-linux` docker image) and restore the database.

**deploy-database.sh**

```
# publish dacpac using sqlpackage
./sqlpackage/sqlpackage /Action:Publish /sf:"/MyDb.dacpac" /tu:sa /tp:Password1 /tdn:MyDb /tsn:localhost
```

**Error:**

> No file was supplied for reference master.dacpac; deployment might fail. When package was created, the original referenced file was
>   located C:$(windows machine path)\MASTER.DACPAC. Initializing
>   deployment (Failed)
>   An error occurred during deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue. Error SQL0: The reference to external elements from
>   the source named 'master.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no
>   such source is loaded. Warning SQL72025: No file was supplied for
>   reference master.dacpac; deployment might fail. When package was
>   created, the original referenced file was located C:$(windows machine
>   path)\MASTER.DACPAC.
>
> An error occurred while adding references.  Deployment cannot
>   continue. The command '/bin/sh -c sh /deploy-database.sh' returned a
>   non-zero code: 1

I have tried adding `master.dacpac` to the project directly and also copying it to the docker image but the same error occurs.

How can I restore a dapac in a linux environment that has a reference to master.dacpac?

Comment: Even if you copy `master.dacpac` to the same folder as `mydb.dacpac` and run sqlpackage with `/p:IncludeCompositeObjects=true` it still fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, my solution was to rename the dacpac files UPPERCASE, (ex: `MASTER.DACPAC`) which worked for me, as well as making the directory with the dacpac files the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried adding master.dacpac to the project directly and also
>   copying it to the docker image but the same error occurs.

Make sure `master.dacpac` file is in the current working directory. Since your `MyDb.dacpac` file exists in the root directory, copy the `master.dacpac` file there and execute the `sqlpackage` command in the context of the root directory.

The example below specifies an absolute reference to `sqlpackage` (in case it's not already in your path) and a relative reference to your user dacpac (although an absolute reference will work too).

```
cd /
/sqlpackage/sqlpackage /Action:Publish /sf:"MyDb.dacpac" /tu:sa /tp:Password1 /tdn:MyDb /tsn:localhost
```

Comment: I'm not directly working on this anymore. If someone can confirm this fixes the issue, I will accept as the answer. @tgn12 could you comment here if this fixed it for you?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy, I did test this and the db was successfully deployed. However, if you can't test yourself and want independent verification, that's fine.

Comment: NOTE: for my own projects, I had to rename the other referenced files to all-caps, based on the error output... such as MYFOO.DACPAC and MASTER.DACPAC in the directory I was using.

Comment: @Tracker1 - making the filename MASTER.DACPAC case sensitive is the answer